# JUnit Test Suite- Only include Specific tests, not every test in the Class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, test-suite

I am setting up a Junit `Test Suite`. I am aware of how to set up a test suite using the standard method that runs all tests in a class, for example [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-suite-test-example/).

Is it possible to create a `test suite` and only run certain tests from several different classes?

If so, how do I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a test suite and only run certain tests from
>   several different classes?

**Option (1) (prefer this):** You can actually do this using `@Category` for which you can look [here](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.html)

**Option (2):** You can do this with few steps as explained below:

You need use JUnit custom Test `@Rule` and with a simple custom annotation (given below) in your Test case. Basically, the Rule will evaluate the required condition before running the Test. If the pre-condition is met, Test method will be executed, otherwise, Test method will be ignored.

Now, you need all the Test classes to your `@Suite` as usual.

The code is given below:

**MyTestCondition Custom Annotation:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyTestCondition {

        public enum Condition {
                COND1, COND2
        }

        Condition condition() default Condition.COND1;
}
```

**MyTestRule class:**

```
public class MyTestRule implements TestRule {

        //Configure CONDITION value from application properties
    private static String condition = "COND1"; //or set it to COND2

   @Override
   public Statement apply(Statement stmt, Description desc) {

           return new Statement() {

         @Override
         public void evaluate() throws Throwable {

                 MyTestCondition ann = desc.getAnnotation(MyTestCondition.class);

                 //Check the CONDITION is met before running the test method
                 if(ann != null &&  ann.condition().name().equals(condition)) {
                         stmt.evaluate();
                 }
         }         
       };
    }
}
```

**MyTests class:**

```
public class MyTests {

        @Rule 
        public MyTestRule myProjectTestRule = new MyTestRule();

        @Test
        @MyTestCondition(condition=Condition.COND1)
        public void testMethod1() {
                //testMethod1 code here
        }

        @Test
        @MyTestCondition(condition=Condition.COND2)
        public void testMethod2() {
                //this test will NOT get executed as COND1 defined in Rule
                //testMethod2 code here
        }

}
```

**MyTestSuite class:**

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({MyTests.class
})
public class MyTestSuite {  
}
```